# Understanding grid system in bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
    <!-- Tab Content -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="bookmark">
            <h1><center>Book Marks</center></h1>
            <div class="col-lg-3 productholder"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 productholder"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 productholder"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I am a div by col-lg-9 this divides my container into 9 parts? But when I am creating other divs inside col-lg-9, the container is not equally filled.

Comment: hm, not sure i understood you question, could you please rephrase or add some details or explanation ?

Comment: Read the Bootstrap docs.

Comment: I read the docs and many people suggested me to read this http://www.helloerik.com/bootstrap-3-grid-introduction blog too. But I had few doubts. But now it seems I am good to go. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a div of `col-lg-9`, you take the horizontal space of nine columns (of 12) of the wrapping container.

But that means that there must be some kind of container. See this code.

```
<!-- still full width -->
<div class="col-lg-9" style="background-color:green;">R</div>

<!-- 9/12 -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-9" style="background-color:blue;">R</div>
</div>
```

So to rephrase your understanding: if you are a `div` of `container`, you devide the horizontal space into 12 columns. The `col-??-xx` classes each take the horizontal space of xx/12 from the wrapping container (or sometimes `row` or `col-??-xx`-`div`'s). But take note that the grid needs to start with a `container` or `container-fluid` which initially provides the 12 columns.

The bootstap documentation has a very good part on its [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) which you would want to read for further information. If you are more the practical type of learner, I would recommend inspecting the code of the [grid examples](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) provided by bootstrap.

Comment: I can understand that col-lg-9 divides my colums in into 9 parts out of 12. Now when I am in the container of 9 columns further I can create col-lg-3 which I would take 3/9 columns and further if I make 2 more div of col-lg-3 I would complete the area of 9 columns created before, right? I am getting the things on the right track?

Comment: basically, if you mean you nest the `col-lg-3` within the `col-lg-9` you are right. Otherwise, if you place them on the same level (dont nest them) there would be like 2 rows, one fille by the `col-lg-9` and `col-lg-3` and the second filled half way by the 2 remaining `col-lg-3`'s. I strongly recommend visitin [bootly](http://bootply.com/new#) and just trying it out. its a good place to start learning these things.

Comment: ya exactly that was the right technical word of nesting divs into each other. Thank You Nozzleman.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u9wsvvx6/3/ I am attaching the fiddle. This is exactly what I am not getting why I am able to add fourth col-md-3 div when my main container class is col-md-9.

Comment: yeah, basically, the wrapping `col-md-9` provides a *sub-grid* of 12 columns if you want. so you can place 4 `col-md-3` (which equals 12) in it. Adding a fifth `col-md-3` is no problem, but it would open up kind of a new row within the `col-md-9`. This is what column nesting is about. You dont need to calculate from scratch all the time. Im not sure how deep you can nest though, but for my purposes, it was always enough.

Comment: ok so its a new sub grid of 12 coloumns, this was the confusing part. Thanks again :).